# Parse data from JSON API(URL) c#

Tags: c#, json, api

I am trying to parse JSON data from this API:

I wrote that on Main Form:

```
void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
    {
        var json = webClient.DownloadString("URL");
        var user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(json);
        MessageBox.Show(User.callsign);
    }
}
```

And I created a class where I convert JSON data to strings with JSONProperty:

```
public class User
{
    [JsonProperty("callsign")]
    public string callsign { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is that when I try the MessageBox.Show(user.callsign) on the main form, I can´t. Because the button1 void is static and the callsign string is not. What can I do??

Regards!!

Comment: Do not vandalize your own posts.

Comment: Is not vandalizing them. I wanted to delete the URL of the API, and I made a mistake :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the Class name and not the variable name. C# is case sensitive.

Change it to this:

```
MessageBox.Show(user.callsign);
```